# Sending unique identifier by email

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3

I am working on asp.net application.

I have to work on a functionality where system admin should be able to send invitations to view user specific documents by email. When user clicks on the invitation, system should be able to recognize the user and open the document.

I am thinking of using 16 digit hash keys against each email and store them in db when admin send the invitation. When user clicks the invitation retrieving the user details using 16 digit hash key.

But I feel there could be a better way of doing it.

Please suggest me to implement the functionality in a better way.

Comment: Isn't that what the `Guid` is for?

Comment: He probably just doesn't realize he can do `Guid.NewGuid().ToString()` to solve his problem.

Comment: Guids are great for this agreed.

Comment: Yea...16 digit hash key is GUID only.

Comment: Do we need to encrypt guid while using it in query string

Answer (score 0):

If your users generally have to log in, you may also want to force them to log in after clicking the link in the email before opening the document (or answer some other question), especially if the documents are at all sensitive in nature. At the very least you should disable the key after they open the document or after some amount of time has passed.

Email accounts get hacked all the time and you don't want the attacker to be able to click on the same link and gain access to any sensitive data.

Comment: Users will not be logging into the system. This is just to send some user specific documents to the user by email.

Answer (score 0):

In Database create a table that contains

```
UserDocuments { UserKey, DocumentKey, GUID, IsRead (false by default)}
```

store user and document key relation in this table.

Generate a random public key (GUID) and store this key in this table and send the same key to user using email, mail , phone or any direct secure way.

Let the document page contain DocumentKey in querystring.

When user opens the document page, authenticate user against the DocumentKey, UserKey in the table.

Don't allow if IsRead is false.

If authentication suceeds ask them to enter GUID.

again check in database if the userid is valid, if yes open the document and mark IsRead true.

Comment: I feel like email and guid would be enough in the table. And it should be enough validating guid and extracting user's email.